# PHP socket_read waits for data to read

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, phpwebsocket

I'm new to socket stuff, here is my piece of code:

```
while (true) {
    $status = $this->client->read();
    echo $status;

    $this->eventQueue->hasEventToSend() ? $this->client->send($this->eventQueue->getEvent()) : null;
}
```

client read method is just:

```
try {
    $status = socket_read($this->socket, $length);
} catch (Throwable $exception) {
    $this->reConnect();
    Log::error($exception->getMessage());

    $status = false;
}

return (string) $status;
```

Nothing will be executed after `$status = $this->client->read()`, untill `socket_read()` reads new data. I would like to stop `socket_read()` acting like waiting for data to read or call `socket_read()` only when there is any data to read. I couldn't get any idea, how to achive that, so I'm asking here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default reading operations are always blocking. You can either use

> socket_set_nonblock($socket)

before calling read() to prevent socket from blocking in read operations, or you can use

> socket_select()

to check if data is available before reading it.

Comment: socket_set_nonblock() works, thanks for helping :)